# Add a clickable "Done" UIButton in the top of keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I would like to add a UIButton in the top of keyboard in my app view. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Refer this http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the `inputAccessoryView` property on your text field.

This can be any view - so, for example, a toolbar with a done button. Example:

```
   UIToolbar * myToolbar = [[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame.... etc
   // Add button to toolbar here

   myTextField.inputAccessoryView = myToolbar;
```